# Invalid object name in CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried CTE combining two table in my below query and getting the Invalid Object error but it exists .Can Anyone guide me?

```
;WITH t1
AS (
    SELECT DepId
        , COUNT(EmpId) AS TotalHeadCount

    FROM Emploee

    WHERE (datepart(yyyy, DOJ) BETWEEN 2005 AND 2017)
        AND STATUS = 0

    GROUP BY DepId
    )
    , t2
AS (
    SELECT DepId
        , COUNT(EmpId) AS NewJoinees

    FROM Emploee

    WHERE (DATEPART(yyyy, DOJ) = 2017)
        AND (DATEPART(mm, DOJ) = 01)
        AND datepart(mm, DOJ) >= 12
        AND STATUS = 0

    GROUP BY DepId
    )
    , t3
AS (
    SELECT Tobehired AS TOBEHIRED
        , OpenPosition AS OPENPOSITION
        , STATUS

    FROM Employee1
    )

SELECT t1.DepId
    , CASE 
        WHEN TotalHeadCount IS NULL
            THEN '0'
        ELSE TotalHeadCount
        END AS TotalHeadCount
    , CASE 
        WHEN NewJoinees IS NULL
            THEN '0'
        ELSE NewJoinees
        END AS NewJoinees
    , Tobehired
    , OpenPosition
    , STATUS

FROM t1

FULL JOIN t2
    ON t1.DepId = t2.DepId

FULL JOIN t3
    ON t1.DepId = t3.DepId
```

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: I don't see a field called `DepID` in your `T3` CTE but you are trying to join on it.

Comment: Are the tables from which you are selecting actually called `emploee` and `employee1`? Does each of the SELECT statements in each CTE definition run on their own without error?

Comment: It's a good idea to include the entire error message when posting an issue.

Comment: Added sql-server tag to question based on function `datepart` and the fact that CTEs are not available in MS Access (the only other database to use datepart())

Comment: @JNevill [Sybase](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36271.1570/html/blocks/X71771.htm)...  I had to look since MS SQL Server started from join venture Sybase code base; but similar enough... :P  (good read as it's a interesting db history https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/euanga/2006/01/19/sql-mythbusters-sql-server-is-really-a-sybase-product-not-a-microsoft-one/)

Comment: @xQbert Sneaky!

Comment: It was, but you're dead on and the depid missing on t3 is also correct. :P

Answer (score 0):

There's a time and a place for use of Common table expressions.  I don't think this was one of them...  Complex joins with nested subqueries, recursion, refactoring for maintainability.  A two table join doesn't seem to fit the bill in my opinion.

```
SELECT E.DEPID
     , sum(case when datepart(yyyy,E.doj) between 2005 and 2017 and status =0 then 1 else 0 end as TotalHeadCount
     , sum(case when E.doj >= cast('2017-01-12' as datetime) then 1 else 0 end as NewJoinees
     , E1.Tobehired
     , E1.OpenPosition
     , E1.STATUS
FROM Employee E
LEFT JOIN Emplyee1 E1
 on E.DepID = E1.DepID
GROUP BY E.DEPID,
       , E1.Tobehired
       , E1.OpenPosition
       , E1.STATUS
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, In the above query before the sum of line E object is missing ,despite adding that I am getting error